# Teradataml error mlengine_alias_definitions_v1.0' is not defined for the current Vantage version 'vantage1.0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyinstaller, teradata

i'm trying to create an exe file which take advantage of teradataml python. I'm trying to create a table in teradata and import the data form pandas dataframe.
here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from teradataml.context.context import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from teradataml.dataframe.copy_to import copy_to_sql
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry
from teradatasqlalchemy import dialect
registry.register('teradata', 'teradatasqlalchemy', 'dialect')

user = 'dbc'
pasw=user
host = '192.168.1.7'

td_engine = create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + pasw + '@'+ host )

create_context(tdsqlengine =td_engine)

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:/krishna/data/FL_insurance_sample1.csv", delimiter=',')
copy_to_sql(df = df, table_name = "Insurece_sample", primary_index="InsurenceID", if_exists="replace")
remove_context()
```

initially i was getting below error however i fixed that one.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata
```

pyinstaller command which i tried:

```
pyinstaller --add-binary "C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\teradatasql\teradatasql.dll;teradatasql"-F pyinstalletest.py
```

the error which i'm getting now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstalletest.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "teradataml\context\context.py", line 459, in create_context
  File "teradataml\context\context.py", line 751, in _load_function_aliases
  File "teradataml\common\utils.py", line 1591, in _check_alias_config_file_exists
teradataml.common.exceptions.TeradataMlException: [Teradata][teradataml](TDML_2069) Alias config file 'C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI63962\teradataml\config\mlengine_alias_definitions_v1.0' is not defined for the current Vantage version 'vantage1.0'. Please add the config file.
[1660] Failed to execute script pyinstalletest
```

please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: Your `create_engine` should specify `teradatasql` dialect not `teradata`. But that might not be the only issue.

Comment: Thanks Fred. One more question. How to achieve LDAP authentication for create_engine in sqlalchemy.

Comment: Append `"/?logmech=LDAP"` to the `teradatasql` URL

Comment: Thanks Fred. i can able to run the code successfully in my local but if i build the same into exe using pyinstaller i'm getting below error. Any idea how to resolve  the issue.

Error:
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradatasql
[10076] Failed to execute script pyinstalletest